# My mess that I'm trying to do with PHP, MySQL, jQuery and css

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, css

Let's see if I can explain what I'm trying to do here..

I've got a MySQL Database with some info stored in it. I am using PHP to query the database, pull my selected entries out, put each one into a separate `<div>` (with Bootstrap framework). I have accomplished this part.
Below is a snippet of what I'm doing...

```
 $query = "SELECT `quote`,`id` FROM `db`";
 $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
      echo ' <div class="panel panel-info">
        <div class="panel-body text-muted" id="'.$row['id'].'">
    '.$row['quote'].'
  </div>
 </div>';
    }
```

Then I am wanting to use jQuery to add a css class on "click" to an individual `<div>` and be able to then use PHP to store the text of the "selected" `<div>` to a variable, for later use.
This is the part I am struggling with, I can not figure out how to separate each individual `<div>` specifically and have jQuery add the class to it, because the "id" of div differs with every result from the db query.

Comment: What @NoahMatisoff? Many people call PHP a joke for many reasons, but I don't see what you're referring to here.

Comment: @NoahMatisoff: What is?

Comment: "use PHP to store the text of the "selected" <div> to a variable", how do you plan to perform this? did you mean a javascript variable, or did you plan to use ajax?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Do you want to attach a click handler to *one* `<div>` or to all of them?  "store [the text] to a variable, for later use"... later use where?  In PHP?  In JavaScript?

Comment: Yes, just to one of the div's created, the one that is "clicked".
Later use in PHP

Comment: "Clicking" is a client action.  Unless... do you know ahead of time which one you want?  If it's later use in PHP, you might need to use AJAX to send the id from JavaScript to your server.

Answer (score 1):

To add a class to a div when it is clicked -

**jQuery**

```
$('div').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('foo');
    var divText = $(this).text(); // store to JavaScript variable
});
```

Now that you have the JavaScript variable stored you can send it to a PHP function via AJAX.

Comment: Yeah, I know how to do that, but I want to only add the class to one of of the div's that I created with the info pulled from the database.

Comment: Ah, you didn't explain that clearly. You have to test the data coming from your database and when the condition is met, add the class.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is add a class to the `<div>`s, and use that to attach the event.

```
<div class="panel-body text-muted click-panel" id="'.$row['id'].'">
```

Then in your JavaScript, do something like:

```
$(function(){
    $('div.click-panel').click(function(){
        var div_id = this.id,
            div_text = $(this).text();

        if(/* some condition eg. div_id === 5 */){
            $(this).addClass('clicked');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: But won't that add it to all of the div's with that class? 
If my pulled info creates 15 different div's, then using the "click" will add it to all of them, no?

Comment: Yes, it will.  Did you only want the event attached to one `<div>`?

Comment: Yes, just one of the div's created, the one that is "clicked"

Comment: How do you know which one?  This will trigger an event when *any* of the `<div>`s is clicked.  Do you only want the event to be attached to one of them?  How would you know which one?

Comment: That's my problem haha. I can't figure out how to differentiate them.

Comment: Are you trying to differentiate them in PHP or in JavaScript?  You know the ID of each one in both languages, is that enough to tell them apart?

Comment: The ID is set in PHP of the div using the info pulled from the database, id="'.$row['id'].'", but I do not know enough to know how to then find the specific div that was clicked, so that I then can use addClass

Comment: That's what my answer is doing.  When you click on any of the `<div>`s it gets its id and text.  In the click handler, compare the `div_id` variable against whatever and then add the class accordingly.